# How to add the picture of my network profile in my profile

Tags: support, profile-page

I have seen some users show a picture of their network profile on the profile tab. How can I add this for my own account?

Comment: Can you give an example for _"picture of their network profile"_ please? It's not completely clear for me what you mean.

Comment: Are you talking about ["flairs"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair)? Those customizable boxes that tell visitors what your reputation points on SE are,  which you copy and paste on personal websites.

Comment: This: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/16963238.png - like here:

Comment: Yes, @Mari-LouA I am talking about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your [Edit Profile & Settings -> Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)
2. Under the "How do I use it?" section, copy the HTML code which is in the "Normal flair" or "Combined flair" section.
3. Paste the HTML content in the [Edit Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) -> "About me" section.
4. Now, go to your [Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) and click the "Update profile Info" link, in the model dialog window, select the Stack Overflow site in the "Choose a site to copy profile information from:" drop down list.
5. Now you can see your combined flair in the Network Profile.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable piece of advice!